# remote desktop through xtightvncviewer share clipboard

Tags: remote-desktop, sharing, vnc, clipboard

I am using xtightvncviewer on a ubuntu machine to connect to the remote desktop of another Ubuntu machine. How can I configure this to share the clipboard, so that I can copy and paste from one another?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the menu you get when you press F8 you can select to copy the clipboard from one to the other and vice-versa.